# Best way to get map overlays from a server to Android \ iPhone client

Tags: android, iphone

I want to implement a client app for Android and iPhone, which will get from a servlet data about specific locations (X pos, Y pos, short description and url to image), and will represent it on mapView. I have no problem implementing all map issues, but I have a question regarding how to transfer all data. Would it be best to transfer the data from the server by some XML file, or maybe there is more efficient way to transfer this data?

All implementations are Google map based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either XML or JSON for trasfering data from the server.